Fast integer sqrt using Math.Sqrt
I'm trying to calculate the square root of integer values. It doesn't need to be very accurate, but it should be fast and deterministic across platforms. I'm using this for a RTS game with lockstep networking.
I'm considering just casting the value to double and use Math.Sqrt, which I assume has hardware acceleration and should be plenty fast. But can I count on this being perfectly deterministic across platforms for all possible inputs (on say a uint64), including the cast back to an integer? From my googling on the subject it seems like floating point sqrt is typically deterministic across platforms (unlike e.g. cos/tan), but does anyone know more about this?

"deterministic across platforms" will be tough as floating point implementations can (ever so slightly) differ across platforms. Most games that need 100% determinism just stick with fixed point for this reason

Can you drop support for 32-bit x86? That's one of the big "problem platforms" due to the x87 80-bit intermediate results weirdness.

Most hardware sqrt algorithms these days are faithfully rounded, but it is impossible to guarantee by testing that there isn't one special case in 2^64 where they differ. It would take around 4 x 10^9s ~ 130 years to exhaustively test every possibility. You might get it down to 0.26 years for every 53 bit mantissa value and odd/even exponent. We rely on formal proofs that sqrt is correctly rounded. On the latest hardware sqrt is almost the same speed as division - which is rather impressive. If you have to be sure then apply one iteration of int64 NR to the result from FP sqrt.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Binary_numeral_system_.28base_2.29

Best way is to limit the precision (number of decimal places).  If you do not need accurate results use 4 decimal places.

it might be much better to use Math.ReciprocalSqrtEstimate and Math.ReciprocalEstimate and do a few more Newton-Raphson iterations

@user555045 actually x87 support for a full precision 64 bit integer arguments without any rounding means that in this instance it should return perfect results. It is the real world of rounding to nearest that causes trouble for ordinary double precision.

@MartinBrown being different is a problem, and even if x87 could compute the exact answer it's non-deterministic when used from a high level language: at any time a 80-bit float may be spilled to memory and reloaded as a 64-bit float, whenever compilers feel like doing do.

I think you can be assured that it will not be deterministic across all platforms if there are any where the program or the floating point hardware can have its rounding mode altered from the usual settings.
There is also a more troubling issue when the input value exceeds 2^52 so that the mantissa of a double floating point cannot accurately represent the input value y. For some unlucky values of y rounding to nearest will result in a spurious answer for x that doesn't satisfy x*x <= y. They are quite rare. I sampled them and get 1:10^8 at the onset of trouble and 3:10^7 for numbers >2^63.
I didn't detect any failures for y < 10^11 but that is a drop in the ocean compared to the total range of an int64. It looks to me like you can safely use sqrt(y) provided that you sanitise the result to guard against the rare exceptions where rounding error causes trouble (and rounding rules or guard digits may vary slightly with some go-faster CPUs).
The refinement I suggest in integer arithmetic should be fast since it is just one multiply a sanity test and a conditional decrement. This is the test code I put together to take a quick look.
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

unsigned int safesqrt(uint64_t y)
{
  // defined to *always* give a deterministic result such that x*x <= y
  // sqrt(y) becomes tricky when y exceeds the 53 bit mantissa of double FP 
  // ironically I think this is one example where x87 80 bit FP would win out!
  // Its 64 bit mantissa can exactly represent every possible integer input.
  // 
  // double results round high for a small fraction of values (approx 1 in 10^8 rising to 3 in 10^7)
  // edge values for y where the mantissa cannot represent the full precision and 
  // sqrt(x) returns a rounded to nearest integer value are the problem

  int x = (unsigned) sqrt((double)y);
  uint64_t x2;
  x2 = x;
  x2 *= x2;
  if (x2 > y) x--; // defend against fail high when y > 0x0010 0000 0000 0000, 2^52
  return x;
}

int main()
{
  uint64_t base, x2, y, z;
  double dx;
  unsigned x, nrx, nrx2, lastbadx = 0, badcount = 0;
  int i = 1;
  base = 1 ;
  base <<= 62;
  printf("base = %18I64x\n", base);
  printf("     N \t\t  y\t\t\t x^2  \t\t     x (double)     (int) x \t NR(x) \t Nr(NR(x))  bad\n");
  for (y = base; y<base+100000000000; y++)
  {
      dx = sqrt((double)y);
      x = (unsigned)(dx);
      x2 = (uint64_t)x;
      x2 *= x2;
      if (x2 > y)  // in an ideal world this shouldn't happen
      {
          nrx = (int)((y / x + x) / 2);
          nrx2 = (int)((y / nrx + nrx) / 2);  // check to see if NR converges or oscillates
          if (x != lastbadx)
          {
              printf(" %5u : %20I64u  %20I64u  %18.10gf  %10u %10u %10u", i++, y, x2, dx, x, nrx, nrx2);
              lastbadx = x;
              badcount++;
          }
          else
              badcount++;
      }
      else
      {
          if (badcount) printf(" [%i]\n", badcount);
          badcount = 0;
      }
  }
}

I left it running overnight and it found about 1400 bad cases in the y>2^63 block. FWIW I found no errors at all in the first 10^11 integer values in just a few minutes (so 10^12, 10^13 would be easily brute force testable). That is still a drop in the ocean compared to the full dynamic range of 10^19.
You could also defend against fail low by checking that x2+2*x+1 > y but I think that the way that rounding to nearest and hardware sqrt works followed by truncation to integer the chances of that ever triggering are vanishingly small.

It's been mathematically proven that sqrt(x*x)== x for all IEEE-754 double where x*x does not underflow or overflow: IEEE double such that sqrt(x*x) ≠ x, square root of square of x equals x, i.e. if x*x isn't inf then taking the square root of it will return the original value even if the mantissa has been rounded off

@phuciv Thanks for that confirmation. It is loading a 64bit integer into a double floating point variable with a 53 bit mantissa and 11 bit exponent that rounds high (ie. to nearest) in a few critical edge cases when x > 2^52. All of the failures are when sqrt(y) is an exact integer value. Perhaps I should add this observation to the answer?

I have a supplementary idea to Dmitry's answer. Math.Sqrt is fast, since your concern is whether this method can generate reliable results, you can do a check when the game is first launched, and the time it takes can be ignored. If the check fails, use the slow method instead or prompt that the HW is not supported.
Here's the check method:
for (long expect = 0, min = 0, odd = 1; expect <= 46340; //sqrt(max-int)
    expect++, min += odd, odd += 2)
{
    var max = min + odd - 1;
    if ((int)Math.Sqrt(min) != expect || (int)Math.Sqrt(max) != expect)
        throw new NotSupportedException();
}

Optimistically speaking, modern chips should be able to provide correct results for sqrt within the int range.

If I uderstand you right, you want an integer square root:
sqrt(0) == 0
sqrt(1) == 1
sqrt(2) == 1
sqrt(3) == 1
sqrt(4) == 2
sqrt(5) == 2
...
sqrt(48) == 6
sqrt(49) == 7
... 

If it's your task and you want determenistic result across platforms, stick to integer values, e.g. O(log(n)) time complexity algorithm
  public static int IntSqrt(int n) {
    ArgumentOutOfRangeException.ThrowIfNegative(n);

    var c = 0;
    var d = 1 << 30; 
                         
    while (d > n) 
      d >>= 2;
    
    for (int x = n; d != 0; d >>= 2) 
      if (x >= c + d) {      
        x -= c + d;        
        c = (c >> 1) + d;  
      }
      else 
        c >>= 1;           
 
    return c; 
  } 

Fiddle
For details see
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Binary_numeral_system_.28base_2.29

You are correct about the integer square root part, that's what I want. I'm currently using something very similar to the algorithm you posted, the problem is that it's very slow. I need something hardware accelerated, but all those functions (as far as I have seen) operate on either floats or doubles, not integers.

So what I need to know is whether I can call (int)Math.Sqrt((double)integerValue) for any integerValue (ulong), can I expect to get the same result on all platforms, e.g. for various processors and operating systems?

@Ollhak: I doubt, NPU hardware is different at least for Intel (they have 80-bit logic inside, so called "extended" or "long double") and AMD (they operate with 64-bit floating points). Technically, we can try to force use 64-bit fp only, but in Java (which has "strictfp" keyword) and in this case compilers add unwanted rounding
